# How to force Exchange 2010 setup to use different languages then system one

Tags: installation, exchange-2010, language

Does anyone know how to force Exchange 2010 setup to use english language on german system? I have to install Exchange 2010 on german system and everything is well in german :-( which heavily complicates installation/configuration.

MadBoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

1. Download [MUI for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=03831393-eef7-48a5-a69f-0ce72b883df2&displaylang=en)
2. Installation is painless and should install without any reboot
3. After installation is done go to:

   a) press Start
   b) Control Panel
   c) Region And Language
   d) Change tab to Keyboard and Languages
   e) In display language change it to 
   f) LogOff when prompted. After Logging in language will be  and installation will go in this language.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you shloud be asked for the language as you can see in the tutorial below:
http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/migration-deployment/installing-exchange-server-2010-beta-part1.html

HTH

Comment: I wasn't asked.. it started as german and then allowed me to downloadm ore languages but it always stayed german. THere was no visible option to change it (i had to run separare exchange install on 2nd server to be able to know what they ask). But i guess maybe i could change the language and see.

Comment: +1 for you because thanks to screen shots attached in link you posted I had an idea to look for MUI packs since i didn't had option to change language and on screen shot it clearly was showing one.